# multilingual articles in joomla

Tags: php, multilingual, joomla2.5

I need help in changing the language of joomla2.5.4 contents.

I have installed german language pack and use language switcher for switching languages.

i have done all the steps its changing the language of joomla's own articles but not mine's article how i do that?? i want to keep one url of article and on changing the language how mine created article language will change ?

Sorry for bad english.. I have follow all these steps given in this url 
[Building Multi-lingual Joomla 2.5 Sites](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/joomla-multi-lingual/)

Please help me to solve this problem. where im doing wronge ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the tutorial from the [Joomla! Documentation - Language Switcher Tutorial for Joomla 1.6](http://docs.joomla.org/Language_Switcher_Tutorial_for_Joomla_1.6)

For me it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for this link. Falang has solved my problem. here is the link http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/multi-lingual-joomla/.